# Converting NLP to CSP: Story Consistency

Tags: nlp, clause, constraint-satisfaction, knowledge-base-population

Background: I would like to know if anyone has succeeded in converting Natural Language to a knowledge base representative of a constraint satisfaction problem. I want preform constraint satisfaction on a person's statements in order to see if any inconsistencies are present while preforming a resolution proof on the statements. This could be used in a courtroom or during election debates.

So to lay out my idealistic story consistency algorithm:

```
A first statement comes in, convert it and add it to the Knowledge Base (KB)
While next
     get next statement
     convert statement to clause
     negate clause, 
     add negated clause to KB
     check for contradiction (perform resolution)
     report finding
     remove the original clause to see if the story changes again
     add the new clause
```

How would I convert a statement to a usable clause?

For example:

```
~A B C 
a ~B C
```

Comment: It's probably a very hard problem – even for humans. Imagine two people performing the conversion manually in parallel (working on the same statements independently). In what percentage of the cases do you expect them to agree?

Comment: Absolutely, it is a hard problem. I believe real use is in the algorithm reporting that it might have found something to a human for further review.